# SQL inner join performance data duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

table -- > qt

| qstnId | tagId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |

table --> question

| qid |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

qid is primary key and qstnId is Fk

now when i'm running query -->

```sql
mysql> select tagId from qt inner join question on qt.qstnId = 1;
```

it's returning;

| tagId |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 1 |

My question is why am i getting duplicate data here.

Comment: Your join isn't valid, you're not comparing the column values from the two tables. Also, why do you need a join if you're selecting from and querying against the same table?

Comment: ON condition selects all rows from `qt` where `qstnId = 1`. 2 rows. And it is joined to 2 rows from another table - total is 4 output rows.

Comment: @fubar What is"valid" supposed to mean? The query returns rows that satisfy a certain condition. Every join does. (Not necessarily the one desired.)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: @philipxy, poor choice of words perhaps, but it’s not a valid query for the described use case.

Answer (score 0):

**Filtering**

`qt.qstnId = 1` is a filtering clause; it belongs in a `WHERE` clause.

**Relation**

`qt.qstnId = question.qid` states how the tables are related via a `JOIN`.  It belongs in an `ON` clause after the `JOIN`.

Fix your query; if you still have concerns; provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see if you have the necessary indexes (for performance).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT tagId 
FROM qt 
INNER JOIN question on qt.qstnId = question.qid
WHERE qid=1;
```